# How to sort columns with scientific number with DT::datatables

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I have the following code using **[RStudio DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('example')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$example <- DT::renderDataTable({
      table = cbind(LETTERS[1:5],c("9.95e-04","9.93e-06","9.93e-02","9.49e-03","9.10e-02"))
      table
    },   options = list(
      columnDefs = list(list(type = "scientific", targets = 1))
    ))
  }
)
```

But it doesn't sort the scientific column as I intended. What's the right way to do it?

[image]

The correct descending order should be:

```
V1         V2
 C     0.0993
 E      0.091
 D    0.00949
 A   0.000995
 B 0.00000993
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657271/ordering-factors-in-data-table-using-dt-package

Comment: Your V2 is a character, not numeric. Currently it's sorted alphanumerically. Once you coerce it to numeric, sorting should work.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik But I want to preserve the scientific notation. If I do `as.numeric` the scientific notation is gone.

Comment: There are several possibilities. You can create a third numeric column and sort the data.frame according to it. You would not be displaying it. Another option is to change `options(scipen = -20); 2.1`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Can you give example code?

Comment: If you copy&paste the above "chunk" I posted with options, it will print `[1] 2.1e+00`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik In actual code I have many columns only want to sort particular columns with scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the implementation of the first solution I proposed in the comment section.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "V1         V2
 C     0.0993
 E      0.091
 D    0.00949
 A   0.000995
 B 0.00000993", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "character"))
xy$V3 <- as.numeric(xy$V2)

xy[order(xy$V3, decreasing = TRUE), c("V1", "V2")]

  V1         V2
1  C     0.0993
2  E      0.091
3  D    0.00949
4  A   0.000995
5  B 0.00000993
```

*EDIT*

You could try this with your example. Notice that I use a data.frame. Matrix is not an appropriate structure for this solution.

```
output$example <- DT::renderDataTable({
  xy <- data.frame(letter = LETTERS[1:5], value = c("9.95e-04","9.93e-06","9.93e-02","9.49e-03","9.10e-02"))
  xy$num_val <- as.numeric(as.character(xy$value))
  xy[order(xy$num_val, decreasing = TRUE), c("letter", "value")]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you give example with *Shiny*, *DT*

Comment: @neversaint I added a small chunk which might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the formatting in JavaScript:

```
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(
  V1 = LETTERS[1:5],
  V2 = c(9.95e-04, 9.93e-06, 9.93e-02, 9.49e-03, 9.10e-02)
)

js <- c(
  "function(row, data, displayNum, index){",
  "  var x = data[1];",
  "  $('td:eq(1)', row).html(x.toExponential(2));",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  df, rownames = FALSE, 
  options = list(
    rowCallback = JS(js)
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still struggling with this you could format the data using a combination of as.numeric() and formatC.

```r
# Example data frame
table_data <- data.frame(
  pvalue = c(0.0000000000000002320234057340785, 0.00000000000000345, 0.0320320320),
  padj = c(0.000000005670234057340785, 0.000000000000000456, 0.0520320320)
)

print(table_data)
#>         pvalue         padj
#> 1 2.320234e-16 5.670234e-09
#> 2 3.450000e-15 4.560000e-16
#> 3 3.203203e-02 5.203203e-02

# Convert pvalue and padj columns to scientific notation and back to number
table_data$pvalue <- as.numeric(formatC(table_data$pvalue, format = "e", digits = 2))
table_data$padj <- as.numeric(formatC(table_data$padj, format = "e", digits = 2))

print(table_data)
#>     pvalue     padj
#> 1 2.32e-16 5.67e-09
#> 2 3.45e-15 4.56e-16
#> 3 3.20e-02 5.20e-02
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>