# Conditional (row-wise) formating of currency, number, and percentage in R DT (datatable)

Tags: r, dt

I have column in my DT output (in Shiny) that has a numeric value whose units depend on another column. Some values are percentages, some are currency, and some are plain numbers.

For example, I would like to turn this input...

| DefaultFormat | Value |
| --- | --- |
| PCT | 12345.67 |
| DOLLAR | 12345.67 |
| NUMBER | 12345.67 |

...into this DT output:

| DefaultFormat | Value |
| --- | --- |
| PCT | 123.45% |
| DOLLAR | $12,345 |
| NUMBER | 12,345.67 |

The `formatCurrency()`, `formatPercentage()` and `formatRound()` functions do what I need for each of these respective formats but they affect the entire column instead specific cells. On the other hand `formatStyle()` can target specific cells in a column based on another column but I can't figure out a way to have it change the contents rather than the styles.

Furthermore, I tried setting the class using `formatStyle()` in the hopes that in the .css file I could then target, e.g. `.pctclass:after` and `.currencyclass:before` but it ignores the class attribute.

What is a good way to get the conditional behavior of `formatStyle()` but for numbers, percentages, and currencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: here's a solution borrowing from the approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657820/6851825

You are seeking to sort a formatted column based on the underlying data instead of its varied formatted appearance. You can do this by using an unformatted helper column to handle the sorting:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  DefaultFormat = c("PCT", "DOLLAR", "NUMBER"),
  Value = c(54.54, 12345.67, 12345.67)
) %>%
  mutate(Value_fmt = case_when(DefaultFormat == "PCT" ~ scales::percent(Value),
                           DefaultFormat == "DOLLAR" ~ scales::dollar(Value),
                           DefaultFormat == "NUMBER" ~ scales::comma(Value),
                           TRUE ~ as.character(Value)) %>%
           forcats::fct_reorder(Value), .after = 1) %>%
  
  DT::datatable(rownames = FALSE, options = list(columnDefs = list(
    list(orderData = 2, targets = 1),
    list(visible=FALSE, targets = 2))))
```

For example, note how `5 454%` appears before the other entries even though it is alphabetically later:

[image]

Comment: The problem with doing this in R is that it converts the column to characters, so DT will sort them alphabetically instead of numerically whereas if the formatting is done in JS/CSS then the sorting is still by numeric value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and post an update. What is the purpose of `fct_reorder` here?

Comment: I don't understand DT enough yet to know why, but the formatting is dropped without it...

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked. Also, I did not have to turn any columns to factors.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not `DT`-specific, it wasn't clear if that was a requirement.)

You can group or split and assign:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)
dat <- data.frame(fmt = sample(c("PCT","DOLLAR","NUMBER"), 10, replace = TRUE), value = round(runif(10, 10, 9999), 2))

dat %>%
  group_by(fmt) %>%
  mutate(value2 = switch(fmt[1],
    PCT=scales::percent(value),
    DOLLAR=scales::dollar(value),
    NUMBER=scales::percent(value),
    as.character(value))
  )
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
# # Groups:   fmt [3]
#    fmt    value value2   
#    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    
#  1 PCT    1816. 181 621% 
#  2 NUMBER 4058. 405 836% 
#  3 DOLLAR 8536. $8,536.10
#  4 DOLLAR 9763. $9,763.24
#  5 PCT    2266. 226 577% 
#  6 PCT    4453. 445 320% 
#  7 PCT     759. 75 897%  
#  8 PCT    6622. 662 171% 
#  9 PCT    3881. 388 123% 
# 10 DOLLAR 8370. $8,369.69
```

An alternative would be to use `case_when` and it would come up with very similar results, but it will be working one string at a time; this method calls the format function once per *group*, perhaps a bit more efficient. (Over to you if that's necessary.)

Comment: Yes, DT is a requirement, that is why I added the DT tag and mentioned DT in the title. As with the above answer, the problem is that `scales` converts the column to characters, so DT will sort them alphabetically instead of numerically whereas if the formatting is done in JS/CSS then the sorting is still by numeric value.

Comment: I see the requirement for a DT solution ... not sure how to do that. Good luck.