# Sorting factor columns of a datatable in R using factor values

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, datatable

I'm working in R and I have different dataframes all with different / multiple columns defined as factor. Then I visualize these dataframes as datatables inside my R Shiny App. When I sort any of the columns of type factor, the sorting is alphabetical and it doesn't take into account the actual factor values. Hence, I'm trying to create a function like the one below such that it checks if the input dataframe has factor columns and automatically fix their sorting 'issue' such that they are not sorted alphabetically but instead using the actual factor values.
I found an interesting question here [Ordering factors in data table using DT package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657271/ordering-factors-in-data-table-using-dt-package) however, this would be for one column only.
Would you know how to fix my attempt below?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define a function to create a datatable with factor columns sorted by factor values
create_datatable <- function(df) {
  # Identify the factor columns
  factor_cols <- sapply(df, is.factor)
  
  # Create a list of column definitions for factor columns
  factor_defs <- lapply(which(factor_cols), function(i) {
    list(targets = i-1, type = 'natural')
  })
  
  # Create the datatable with column definitions
  DT::datatable(df, 
                options = list(orderClasses = TRUE),
                rownames = FALSE,
                class = 'cell-border stripe',
                columnDefs = factor_defs
  )
}


# Define a sample dataframe with factor columns
df <- data.frame(
  x = factor(c("A", "B", "C")),
  y = factor(c("Low", "High", "Medium")),
  z = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Maybe")),
  a = c(1, 2, 3),
  b = c(4, 5, 6)
)

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

# Define the server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # Create the datatable with factor columns sorted by factor values
    create_datatable(df)
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When I run your code I get error `Warning: Error in DT::datatable: unused argument (columnDefs = factor_defs)`

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm asking. how can I fix it? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the page for [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) and then convert their example to an R structure, we can see what type of nested-list it is looking for:

```r
str(jsonlite::fromJSON('[
        { "targets": [0, 1], "visible": true},
        { "targets": "_all", "visible": false }
    ]'))
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ targets:List of 2
#   ..$ : int  0 1
#   ..$ : chr "_all"
#  $ visible: logi  TRUE FALSE
```

whereas your list is

```r
str(factor_defs)
# List of 3
#  $ x:List of 2
#   ..$ targets: num 0
#   ..$ type   : chr "natural"
#  $ y:List of 2
#   ..$ targets: num 1
#   ..$ type   : chr "natural"
#  $ z:List of 2
#   ..$ targets: num 2
#   ..$ type   : chr "natural"
```

Further, it needs all of that to be within another `list`, and then applied within the `options=` list.

We can fix it by using this instead of your `lapply` version:

```r
create_datatable <- function(df) {
  # Identify the factor columns
  factor_cols <- sapply(df, is.factor)
  if (any(factor_cols)) {
    # Create a list of column definitions for factor columns
    factor_defs <- do.call(
      c,
      unname(Map(function(orig, lvl) list(list(targets=orig, orderData=lvl),
                                          list(targets=lvl, visible=FALSE)),
                 which(factor_cols) - 1, ncol(df) + seq_len(sum(factor_cols)) - 1))
    )
    df <- cbind(df, lapply(df[,factor_cols,drop=FALSE], function(z) match(z, levels(z))))
  } else factor_defs <- NULL
  # Create the datatable with column definitions
  DT::datatable(df, 
                options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, columnDefs = factor_defs),
                rownames = FALSE,
                class = 'cell-border stripe'
  )
}
```

Demonstration:

```r
tmp <- mtcars # no factors
create_datatable(tmp)
# sort by `cyl`
```

[image: mtcars, no factors, sort by cyl, is a natural sort]

```r
tmp$cyl <- factor(tmp$cyl, levels = c("6", "4", "8"))
create_datatable(tmp)
```

[image: mtcars, cyl is a factor, sort by cyl, ordered by levels]

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. I just became dad so I just saw your answer right now. I tried your solution but it doesn't work. To give you a concrete example, I created: "tmp <- mtcars".  Then  "tmp$cyl <- factor(tmp$cyl, levels = c("6", "4", "8"))".  Then, I pass tmp to your function create_datatable(tmp). If I sort column cyl, data goes from either 4 to 8 or from 8 to 4. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Angelo, congratulations! Many late-nights/early-mornings, I'm sure. See my edit, better-tested this time. Lmk if there are other problems.

Comment: it works like a charm! Thank you so much!